# Receiving calls with Sipek Voip SDK

Tags: c#, voip

I have been playing around with the Sipek Voip SDK and I am having trouble receiving calls with it.

The tutorial online is less than helpful and I was wondering if anybody here has used it in the past? I can register and place calls but I have no idea how to even handle receiving a call at this point. I will paste my code below. Thanks!

Here is my main class where I keep the interface for the callbacks.

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
        #region Properties
        // Get call manager instance
        CCallManager CallManager
        {
            get { return CCallManager.Instance; }
        }

        private PhoneConfig _config = new PhoneConfig();
        internal PhoneConfig Config
        {
            get { return _config; }
        }

        private IStateMachine _call = null;

        #endregion


        #region Constructor
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // register callbacks
            CallManager.CallStateRefresh += new DCallStateRefresh(CallManager_CallStateRefresh);
            pjsipRegistrar.Instance.AccountStateChanged += new Sipek.Common.DAccountStateChanged(Instance_AccountStateChanged);

            // Inject VoIP stack engine to CallManager
            CallManager.StackProxy = pjsipStackProxy.Instance;

            // Inject configuration settings SipekSdk
            CallManager.Config = Config;
            pjsipStackProxy.Instance.Config = Config;
            pjsipRegistrar.Instance.Config = Config;

            // Initialize
            CallManager.Initialize();
            // register accounts...
            pjsipRegistrar.Instance.registerAccounts();
        }
        #endregion

        #region Callbacks
        void Instance_AccountStateChanged(int accountId, int accState)
        {

            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background, (ThreadStart)delegate
           {
               OnRegistrationUpdate(accountId, accState);
           });
        }

        void CallManager_CallNotification(int sessionId)
        {

        }
        void CallManager_CallStateRefresh(int sessionId)
        {
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background, (ThreadStart)delegate
            {
                OnStateUpdate(sessionId);
            });

        }
        #endregion

       public void OnRegistrationUpdate(int accountId, int accState)
        {
            authenticationStatus_Text.Text = accState.ToString(); 
        }

        public void OnStateUpdate(int sessionId)
       {
           callStatus_Text.Text = CallManager.getCall(sessionId).StateId.ToString();
       }

        private void release_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            dial_Text.Clear();
            CallManager.onUserRelease(_call.Session);
        }

        private void dial_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _call = CallManager.createOutboundCall(dial_Text.Text);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my own problem.  I was using an older version of the dll that does not seem to support the incoming call callback.